# Can my school see what I searched for while logged in?

Tags: privacy, account-security

I'm on my laptop at home and I wasn't logged into any Google account but I was on my school's Microsoft account. Can the school still see my searches?

Comment: What browser were you using? Edge or something else

Comment: The best response to this question is "maybe" unless you provide a lot more information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.